# Parallel ForEach Workflow Doesn't Export-CSV

Tags: csv, powershell, foreach, parallel-processing, workflow

I'm trying to write a workflow that will evaluate each line of a CSV against each additional line to estimate which lines might be duplicates. I have 23,000+ lines however, so Powershell is going to take 5 days to execute this script.

I turned it into a workflow, so I could try running a parallel foreach loop and had to modify the way I assign variables, etc. for workflow limitations. I finally got the workflow to work without throwing errors, but it doesn't actually export a CSV file.

I can see `powershell.exe` using 20% CPU in Task Manager and I can break into the debugger and see that it is working through the lines. Just no CSV.

Any ideas?

```
workflow Leads-Workflow
{
    $leads = Import-CSV C:\Temp\leads.csv
    $Count = $null
    $time = Get-Date
    foreach -Parallel ($lead in $leads)
    {
        for($i=0;$i -le $leads.count;$i++)
        {
            $Poss = 0
            $Dupes = 0
            if($lead.FullName -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].FullName -ne $null -AND $lead.FullName -ne $leads[$i].FullName)
            {
                for($l=0;$l -lt $lead.FullName.Length;$l++)
                {
                    if($lead.FullName[$l] -eq $leads[$i].FullName[$l])
                    {
                    $Poss += $l
                    $l += $lead.FullName.Length
                    }
                }
            }
            elseif($lead.FullName -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].FullName -ne $null -AND $lead.FullName -eq $leads[$i].FullName)
            {
                $Poss += ($lead.FullName.Length*5)
            }
            if($lead.Account -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].Account -ne $null -AND $lead.Account -ne $leads[$i].Account)
            {
                for($l=0;$l -lt $lead.Account.Length;$l++)
                {
                    if($lead.Account[$l] -eq $leads[$i].Account[$l])
                    {
                    $Poss += $l
                    $l += $lead.Account.Length
                    }
                }
            }
            elseif($lead.Account -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].Account -ne $null -AND $lead.Account -eq $leads[$i].Account)
            {
                $Poss += ($lead.Account.Length*5)
            }
            if($lead.Street -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].Street -ne $null -AND $lead.Street -ne $leads[$i].Street)
            {
                for($l=0;$l -lt $lead.Street.Length;$l++)
                {
                    if($lead.Street[$l] -eq $leads[$i].Street[$l])
                    {
                    $Poss += $l
                    $l += $lead.Street.Length
                    }
                }
            }
            elseif($lead.Street -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].Street -ne $null -AND $lead.Street -eq $leads[$i].Street)
            {
                $Poss += ($lead.Street.Length*5)
            }
            if($lead.City -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].City -ne $null -AND $lead.City -ne $leads[$i].City)
            {
                if($lead.City -eq $leads[$i].City)
                {
                    $Poss += 5
                }
            }
            if($lead.Email -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].Email -ne $null -AND $lead.Email -ne $leads[$i].Email)
            {
                for($l=0;$l -lt $lead.Email.Length;$l++)
                {
                    if($lead.Email[$l] -eq $leads[$i].Email[$l])
                    {
                    $Poss += $l
                    $l += $lead.Email.Length
                    }
                }
            }
            elseif($lead.Email -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].Email -ne $null -AND $lead.Email[$l] -eq $leads[$i].Email)
            {
                $Poss += ($lead.Email.Length*5)
            }
            if($lead.Phone -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].Phone -ne $null -AND $lead.Phone -ne $leads[$i].Phone)
            {
                for($l=0;$l -lt $lead.Phone.Length;$l++)
                {
                    if($lead.Phone[$l] -eq $leads[$i].Phone[$l])
                    {
                    $Poss += $l
                    $l += $lead.Phone.Length
                    }
                }
            }
            elseif($lead.Phone -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].Phone -ne $null -AND $lead.Phone -eq $leads[$i].Phone)
            {
                $Poss += ($lead.Phone.Length*5)
            }
            if($lead.Website -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].Website -ne $null -AND $lead.Website -ne $leads[$i].Website)
            {
                for($l=0;$l -lt $lead.Website.Length;$l++)
                {
                    if($lead.Website[$l] -eq $leads[$i].Website[$l])
                    {
                    $Poss += $l
                    $l += $lead.Website.Length
                    }
                }
            }
            elseif($lead.Website -ne $null -AND $leads[$i].Website -ne $null -AND $lead.Website -eq $leads[$i].Website)
            {
                $Poss += ($lead.Website.Length*5)
            }
            if($Poss -ge 100 -AND $lead.LeadID -ne $leads[$i].LeadID)
            {
                $Dupes += $leads[$i].LeadID + "; "
            }
        }
        $lead = $lead | Add-Member @{Poss=$Poss;Dupes=$Dupes} -PassThru
        Export-CSV C:\temp\Deduped\leads.csv -InputObject $lead -Append -Force
        $Workflow:Count += 1
        Write-Progress -Activity "Deduping Leads . . ." -status "Scanned $Count of $($leads.Count)" -percentComplete (($Count / $leads.Count)*100)
    }
}
Leads-Workflow
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect `Export-Csv` to handle concurrent write attempts?

For finding or removing duplicates from a CSV simply use [`Group-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx).

Find duplicates:

```
$header = 'Account', 'FullName', 'City', 'Street', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Website'

Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\leads.csv' |
  Group-Object $header |
  ? { $_.Group.Count -gt 1 }
```

Remove duplicates:

```
$header = 'Account', 'FullName', 'City', 'Street', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Website'

Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\leads.csv' |
  Group-Object $header |
  ? { $_.Group.Count -eq 1 } |
  select -Expand Group |
  Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\Deduped\leads.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: I'm not simply removing exact duplicates here. I'm evaluating the likelihood of duplicates with fuzzy matching. Export-CSV not being able to handle concurrent write attempts makes sense though. Thank you.

I should expect this to work if I build an array and then write the array to a CSV at the end of the script?

Comment: It doesn't look like that works either. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the for $i loop not being able to run parallel because of the increase occurring in multiple threads, or the $count variable increasing in multiple threads, et cetera.

When I break into the debugger every minute or so, $i has increased by 1 or two even when I set the ThrottleLimit to 4, which seems incredibly slow.